# Combining multiple maven projects into a single repository in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

I am having some standalone maven build and sbt built projects in scala.
These projects are now in different repositories in github.

Now I am trying to keep all these projects in a single repository as different projects.

As the first step I created pom file from all the sbt build projects.
Now i created a new repository and added all these projects as separate modules, each one are having their own pom.xml.

I have a common pom.xml as parent.
I have to implement all the dependencies which are common in the parent pom.xml(how can I use dependencyManagement here)
Each project module should create their own jar file after packaging.

Any leads appreciated!

Comment: So, do you want to create a Maven multi-module project?

Comment: yes It should be multiple modules, which will create a jar for each module. But common dependencies should be in parent pom @JF Meier